# How to structure DBT tables with cyclical dependencies

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have one table containing my members.

| customer_id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 74 |
| 2 | Sarah | 87 |

Everyday, I get a new table containing the current members.

- If a new member has joined, I want to add them.
- If a member has left, I want to nullify their name/id
- If a current member is still a member then I want to keep them as is.

Imagine that I get a new upload with the following rows

| customer_id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Sarah | 87 |
| 3 | Melvin | 23 |

I then want to generate the table

| customer_id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | 74 |
| 2 | Sarah | 87 |
| 3 | Melvin | 23 |

I don't want to nullify anything by mistake and therefore I want to run a few tests on this table before I replace my old one. The way I've done this is by creating a temporary table (let's call it customer_temp). However, I've now created a cyclical dependency since I:

- Need to read the live table *customer* in order to create the *customer_temp*
- Need to replace the live table *customer* with *customer_temp* **after I've run my tests**

Is there anyway I can do this using dbt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroying data is tricky. I would avoid that unless it's necessary (e.g., DSAR compliance).

Assuming the new data is loaded into the same table in your database each day, I think this is a perfect candidate for snapshots, with the option for invalidating hard-deleted records. See the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/snapshots#hard-deletes-opt-in). This allows you to capture the change history of a table without any data loss.

If you turned on snapshots in the initial state, your snapshot table would look like (assuming the existing records had a timestamp of 1/1):

| customer_id | name | age | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 74 | 1/1/2022 |  |
| 2 | Sarah | 87 | 1/1/2022 |  |

Then, after the source table was updated, re-running `dbt snapshot` (today) would create this table:

| customer_id | name | age | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 74 | 1/1/2022 | 5/12/2022 |
| 2 | Sarah | 87 | 1/1/2022 |  |
| 3 | Melvin | 23 | 5/12/2022 |  |

You can create the format you'd like with a simple query:

```sql
select
    case when valid_to is null then customer_id else null end as customer_id,
    case when valid_to is null then name else null end as name,
    age
from {{ ref('my_snapshot') }}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a snapshot and some other logic to solve my use-case.